# Create restful controller action

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to create a restful controller action in my module. But so far all example I can see are in this format `http://mywebsite.com/mycustommodule/controller/action` but what I want to build is something like `http://mywebsite.com/mycustommodule/controller/action/param1/param2` is this possible in Magento 2?

My folder structure is like this

```
app
 - code
    - Vendor
       - Module
           - Controller
               - MyController
                    - TheAction.php
```

So all parameter being pass after TheAction.php should be considered as parameter. It doesn't have to be dynamic as long as the parameter is part of the URL. How do we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Magento 2 allows us to pass parameter like http://mywebsite.com/mycustommodule/controller/action/key/value/key/value/

But if you need fixed parameters and only want to pass the value in URL then this can be done using .htaccess file (not recommended).
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975833/using-htaccess-to-pass-multiple-parameters

I think you can do it directly in the controller using RequestInterface. May below link help you
Link - https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-blog/blob/master/Controller/Router.php
Thanks

Comment: Thanks didn't know Magento default allow that.